# Why can I not overload & with my custom type and uint32_t?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, overloading

I do a lot of work with CAN and to simplify IDs throughout my applications and those of my colleagues, I created a custom type: CanId.
This type simplifies the usage of CAN IDs because it determines whether an identifier is valid or not and also handles some other functionality such as determining whether an extended identifier is being used or not.

I recently came across an issue where I needed to AND some values together (one of them being a CanId) and decided to implement this functionality right in to CanId.
It works for the most part, but two of my overloads have the return type `uint32_t` and the compiler is giving me an interesting error:

```
CanId.hpp:47:18: error: ‘uint32_t Extensions::Can::CanId::operator&(Extensions::Can::CanId&)’ cannot be overloaded
         uint32_t operator &(CanId& x)          { return id & x.id; }
                  ^~~~~~~~
CanId.hpp:40:18: error: with ‘Extensions::Can::CanId Extensions::Can::CanId::operator&(Extensions::Can::CanId&)’
         CanId    operator &(CanId& x)          { return id & x.id; }
```

While CanId is implicitly castable to uint32_t (and some others), when I AND or OR some values, there are cases where I'd need to automatically have them as a uint32_t - having the correct return type in the overload seems to be more readable, rather than explicitly casting the value back to a uint32_t, no?

Why can't I overload these two types/operators? Is it because the type is already implicitly castable to uint32_t?

```
operator int32_t() { return id; }
operator uint32_t() { return id; }
```

Comment: A unique function signature in C++ is determined exclusively by name and parameter amount/type. You just can't have two functions called `ns::bar::foo()` even if they return different types.

Comment: Yup, that explains it thanks.